# What's the equivalent syntax in MySQL for selecting date ranges by YEAR based on MSSQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a MSSQL syntax to select date within 2 years:

```
SELECT 
   column_1
FROM
   XXX
WHERE 
   column_1 BETWEEN DATEADD(Year, -2, '2021-05-12') and '2021-05-12'
```

This works fine, `column_1` only return date within two years of the given date.

However, I'm trying to convert it to MySQL syntax, here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
   column_1
FROM
   XXX
WHERE 
   column_1 BETWEEN ADDDATE(date('2021-05-10'), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

But this returns dates not only within two years range but also other years, am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Sample input data, desired output data, and current output data would help. But although I'm far from a MySQL expert, something about that 2nd `where` clause looks wrong to me, as you seem to be passing only one value to `between`, so where is the other bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in MS SQL is:

```
WHERE column_1 BETWEEN DATEADD(Year, -2, '2021-05-12') and '2021-05-12'
```

`BETWEEN` is not recommended when working with dates.  In this example, May 12th may be selected twice (if `column_1` is a `date`) or 2021-05-12 00:00:00 would be selected, if the column has a time component -- but no other times for that date.

I would instead *strongly recommend phrasing this to get two complete years as:

```
WHERE column_1 >= DATEADD(Year, -2, '2021-05-13') AND
      column_1 < '2021-05-13'
```

Or in MySQL as:

```
WHERE column_1 >= '2021-05-13' - interval 2 year AND
      column_1 < '2021-05-13'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the date literal to a date, and also you may use direct arithmetic with intervals to substract some number of days in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT column_1
FROM XXX
WHERE column_1 BETWEEN '2021-05-12' - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND '2021-05-12';
```

The above query is somewhat trivial, because we know that 2 years earlier than the date literal is `2019-05-12`.  But the same logic would work if you were using a column rather than a date literal.

Comment: Hi thanks, it works, it should be `2 YEAR` instead of `2 DAY`:)

Comment: @Cecilia Not enough coffee today.